# nodejs mongodb findOne values not accessable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a query for my mongo db database:

```
    var doc = db.collection('locations').find({name: "Washington DC"})
     if (doc) {
         console.log("doc exists", doc.name);
     }else{
        console.log("doc not exists");

     }
```

The doc exists and also contains a name but it always logs undefined.

Comment: A couple of things. First, `find()` returns a Promise, so you have to use the await -keyword to wait for it to complete. So: `var doc = await db.collection...`. And the Promise resolves to an array, if you want only 1 result, use findOne instead of find. Otherwise the name of the first matching document should be accessed with `doc[0].name` instead of `doc.name`

Comment: thanks for your answer you solved my problem but how can i use await in a app.get function to make it callable as a rest api endpoint ?

Comment: Functions that use `await` themselves need the `async` keyword. So, probably something like:
 
```app.get('/route', async (req, res) => {
  const doc = await db.collection('locations').findOne({ name: 'Washington DC' });
  res.json(doc);
})```

Comment: thanks man you solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that you are using the NodeJS driver (pacakge `mongodb`), so the query methods do not return the docs directly. They work with `Promise`'s and callbacks.

In your case, you could use the findOne method like this:

```
db.collection('locations').findOne({name: "Washington DC"}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  if (doc) {
    console.log("doc exists", doc.name);
  } else {
    console.log("doc not exists");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection().find()` returns an array of documents and hence `doc` is an array of objects rather than an object itself.

If you need the query to return just one document you can use `db.collection().findOne()` or you can update your `console.log` statement to look like

```
console.log("doc exists", doc[0].name);
```